# regex.replace #number;#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

What would be the regex expression to find (PoundSomenumberSemiColonPound) (aka #Number;#)? I used this but not working

```
 string st = Regex.Replace(string1, @"(#([\d]);#)", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a character class when using `\d`, and as SLaks points out you need `+` to match one or more digits. Also, since you're not capturing anything the parentheses are redundant too, so something like this should do it

```
string st = Regex.Replace(string1, @"#\d+;#", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `#\d+;#`.

- `\d` matches a single numeric character
- `+` matches one or more of the preceding character.

Comment: Still not working    
Regex.Replace(string1, @"(#([\d+]);#)", string.Empty);

Comment: dont use []. You need Regex.Replace(string1, @"#\d+;#", string.Empty);

Comment: Don't use the square brackets (or, at the least, put the `+` outside of them)

Answer (score 1):

```
(\x23\d+\x3B\x32)
```

`#` and `/` are both used around patterns, thus the trouble. Try using the above (usually when I come in to trouble with specific characters I revert to their hex facsimile (asciitable.com has a good reference)

**EDIT** Forgot to group for replacement.

**EDITv2** The below worked for me:

```
String string1 = "sdlfkjsld#132;#sdfsdfsdf#1;#sdfsdfsf#34d;#sdfs";
String string2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(string1, @"(\x23\d+\x3B\x23)", String.Empty);
Console.WriteLine("from: {0}\r\n  to: {1}", string1, string2);;
```

Output:

```
from: sdlfkjsld#132;#sdfsdfsdf#1;#sdfsdfsf#34d;#sdfs
  to: sdlfkjsldsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsf#34d;#sdfs
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Regex.Replace(string1, @"(\x23\d+\x3B\x32)", string.Empty);
Did not work.

Comment: please see my updated post, worked fine for me. (Are you expecting the result to be placed back in string1 instead of returned as a function result?)

Comment: A slightly more sane regex like `#\d+;#` will also do the trick. This isn't Perl so # and / are not needed. So there's no need to use character codes.

Comment: I am using this on Gridview control in asp.net(ascx file) and will be using this as web part for sharepoint. I wonder if its a good idea to use hex.

Comment: @Jamil: You don't need to use hex here. Please see some of the other answers.

Comment: @Brian: Okay. I am convinced that it will work in Sharepoint. Thanks Everyone....

Comment: @Brian: I was going more for portability's sake and that in _most_ situations (specifically since regex on windows is a port) you'll run in to trouble using the character. I'd rather offer full-disclosure at the cost of a more complex solution than to give a solution that only works in a .NET environment. Though you are 100% correct, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to escape the `#` symbols, they're usually interpreted as comment markers, in addition to [@SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306483/regex-replace-number/4306494#4306494) comment about using `+` to allow multiple digits